# Determine if u is an ancestor of v

Tags: binary-tree, graph-theory

Heres the problem, and my attempted solution.
[image]

My solution:
1. Run a topological sort on the tree, which runs in linear time BigTheta(E+V) where E is the number of edges and V the number of vertices. This puts it in a linked list which also takes constant time.
2. A vertex u would be an ancestor if it has a higher finishing time than vertex v.
3. Look at the 2 vertice's in the linked list and compare their finishing time and return true or false depending on the result from step 2.

Does this sound correct or am i missing something?

Comment: why are you asking if your solution works? you tell us.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "do my work for me" site; for that you should look somewhere like [Rentacoder](http://rentacoder.com). If you want help here, you should post the effort you've made and explain why it didn't work like you'd expect, and someone can probably help you. If you're not writing code to solve this problem, your question is off-topic; if you are, post the code you've written and tell us what isn't working correctly. Thanks. :)

Comment: The question only asks for pseudocode, i dont need to write anything just explain how it would work. It does work for me, but I feel like im missing something small which is what stackoverflow is always good for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your understanding of what "constant time" means is quite correct. "...time BigTheta(E+V) where E is the number of edges and V the number of vertices" is *linear* time, not *constant* time.

Granted, you are allowed to take linear time for the pre-processing, so that's ok, but how are you going to do your step 3 ("Look at the 2 vertice's in the linked list") in constant time?

Comment: He can do it fine because he is only comparing the positions anyway (and the positions can be stored in the vertices. That sad, it doesn't matter because the algorithm is wrong anyway (it can give false positives)

Comment: whoops, brain fart i do know the difference between linear and constant time. Ah, I will update my question to include how i would reference the vertices in step 2 to accomplish this in constant time

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that will work for any tree (not only binary). The pre-processing step is to perform an Euler Tour of the tree (this is just a DFS traversal) and create a list out of this tour. When you visit a node for the first time you append it to the list and when you visit it the last time you append it to the list.

Example:

```
    x
   / \
  y   z
```

The list will look like: `[b(x), b(y), e(y), b(z), e(z), e(x)]`. Here `b(x)` means enter `x` and `e(x)` means leave `x`. Now once you have this list, you can answer the query `is x an ancestor of y` by performing the test `b(x) is before b(y) and e(y) is before e(x)` in the list.

The question is how can you do this in constant time?

For static trees (which is the case for you), you can use a lookup table (aka array) to store the `b/e`, now the test takes constant time. So this solves your problem.